# PySpark - Getting BufferOverflowException while running dataframe.sql on CSV stored in S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks, minio

I was getting the BufferOverflowException when I tried Spark SQL query on CSV stored in S3.

[Here is the link to the CSV and the data schema.](https://gist.github.com/coolboi567/d65254b1ac4b64c5969bd6309d8f8424)

I am actually using GZIP compressed CSV in S3.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([ StructField('is_male', BooleanType(), False), StructField('weight_pounds', DoubleType(), False), ])
df = spark.read.format("minioSelectCSV").schema(schema).load("s3://test/natalityy-1000", compression="gzip")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("natality")
query="SELECT is_male, AVG(weight_pounds) AS avg_weight FROM natality GROUP BY is_male"
df2 = spark.sql(query)
df2.show()
```

Upon executing the snippet above, I am getting the BufferOverflowException. Though the same snippet worked on CSV with 15 entries. So, I am assured that the query works fine.

Here complete exception log:

```java
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o7064.showString.
: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.eventstreaming.MessageDecoder.feed(MessageDecoder.java:38)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream$SelectEventIterator.getNext(SelectObjectContentEventStream.java:207)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream$LazyLoadedIterator.advanceIfNeeded(SelectObjectContentEventStream.java:315)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream$LazyLoadedIterator.hasNext(SelectObjectContentEventStream.java:292)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream$EventStreamEnumeration.getNext(SelectObjectContentEventStream.java:244)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream$LazyLoadedIterator.advanceIfNeeded(SelectObjectContentEventStream.java:315)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream$LazyLoadedIterator.hasNext(SelectObjectContentEventStream.java:292)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SelectObjectContentEventStream$EventStreamEnumeration.hasMoreElements(SelectObjectContentEventStream.java:273)
    at java.io.SequenceInputStream.nextStream(SequenceInputStream.java:109)
    at java.io.SequenceInputStream.read(SequenceInputStream.java:211)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at io.minio.spark.select.SelectCSVRelation.getRows(SelectCSVRelation.scala:86)
    at io.minio.spark.select.SelectCSVRelation.tokenRDD(SelectCSVRelation.scala:96)
    at io.minio.spark.select.SelectCSVRelation.buildScan(SelectCSVRelation.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack trace implies the codepath is using the "S3 Select" mechanism where some of the CSV select/project is done in S3 itself, and the EC2 VM just gets that processed output. Something may be going wrong. See if you can turn that feature off. This is not your code at fault here, though it may be something up with the CSV file, its compression, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The code works well for small data using the same "S3 Select" mechanism.

Comment: Yes, I had tried using the native 'csv' format and was able to successfully run the same query over all 2000251 rows of the big compressed file.
I believe that there is some issue with `Minio-Select` implementation.

Comment: didn't think anyone other than AWS bothered with Select. The S3 Select does one key thing: compensates for the limited bandwidth between EC2 VMs and S3. If you can get the data to spark, it can do all the work itself, splitting up large files as needed, executing work on the splits in parallel.

Comment: Interesting. Your insights are really valuable.

Comment: I did the s3 select binding to the S3A connector; I think the idea is good, but you shouldn't be keeping data in CSV format as it is wrong. Use ORC, Parquet, Avro, and import those CSVs as the ingest